# Persistance ignorance and lazy loading

Tags: c#

Hey I cannot find solution to such a problem:
I'm implementing generic interface for EAV pattern

Want to execute such a code:

```
    Entity<GPS> gps = new Entity<GPS>("Path.To.GPS");
    Console.WriteLine(gps.Attributes.Latitude);
    Console.WriteLine(gps.Attributes.Longitude);
```

Where:

```
    public class GPS : IAttributes
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public IAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public Entity(string path)
        {
            this.Path = path;
        }
    }

    public class Entity<T> : Entity
        where T : IAttributes, new()
    {
        private T attributes = new T();

        new public T Attributes
        {

            get { return attributes; }

            set { attributes = value; }

        }
        public Entity(string path)
            : base(path)
        { }
    }

    public interface IAttributes
    { 
        /* Empty by design */
    }
```

Its easy to add to Entity class method for data loading
iterate through all parameters in T and load them from some source

Easy path:

```
    Entity<GPS> gps = new Entity<GPS>("Path.To.GPS");
    gps.Reload(); // <-- ADD THIS HERE
    Console.WriteLine(gps.Attributes.Latitude);
    Console.WriteLine(gps.Attributes.Longitude);
```

but how to do lazy loading ?

is it possible to "attach" some code to accessor of every property in GPS class without modifying it, don't want to add and base classes or interfaces to it

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [dynamicproxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html). To make use of them you'll need to define properties you'd like to attach code to as virtual. Then you'll be able to attach interceptors. See [a tutorial](http://kozmic.pl/dynamic-proxy-tutorial/) for more details.